# Получить enum c помощью reflection из класса?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Есть некий сторонний класс Document.

В котором есть метод Save принимающий steam и enum.

```
public enum SaveFormat
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Doc = 10,
    Dot = 11,
    Docx = 20
}
```

C помощью Reflection вызываю Save.

```
  object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Document), stream);


        var prop = documentType.GetProperty("SaveFormat");

        MethodInfo methodInfo = documentType.GetMethod ("Save", new [] {typeof(Stream), typeof(SaveFormat)});


            if (methodInfo != null)
            {
                object result = null;
                ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();

                stream.Close();

            if (parameters.Length == 0)
                {
                    //This works fine
                    result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    object[] parametersArray = new object[] { outStream, SaveFormat.Pdf };

                    result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
                }
            }
```

Подскажите как получить SaveFormat enum через reflection, чтобы передавать как входящий параметр в метод Save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать это так

```
var formats = methodInfo.GetParameters()[1]; // получаем тип параметра в методе
// net3.5
var enumVals = Enum.GetValues(formats.ParameterType); // получаем массив возможных значений этого параметра

// net4.0
//var enumVals = formats.ParameterType.GetEnumValues();    

// вызов функции со значением перечисления, равным Doc
object[] parametersArray = new object[] { outStream, enumVals[1] }; 
result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);

// Docx
object[] parametersArray = new object[] { outStream, enumVals[3] };
result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
```